# How do I hide guest list in google calendar using app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I'm using google app script in google sheet to send a calendar invite to contacts. I've grouped my contacts for the events, so each row has 2 column: Event Name and List of Emails.

Using below function (just an example) in the script editor, I'm able to send all the guests a calendar invite. But the invite shows them the list of all the other invited guests (and their emails).

```
function createEvent() {
    emailList = ['a@gmail.com','b@gmail.com','c@gmail.com'];
    var startTime = new Date('May 07, 2020 12:00:00 EST');
    var endTime = new Date('May 07, 2020 14:00:00 EST');
    var description = "Here is the link for the webinar: "; 
    var event = {'location': '','description': description,'guests':emailList+',', 'sendInvites':'True'};
    eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event);
}
```

Google calendar lets you set hide that list if you create the event manually, I checked google apps script documentation, but I couldn't find anything that can hide the list for guests. Since I don't have much experience with app script, thought may be the stack overflow community can provide me a direction. Please let me know if I'm missing anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to turn off "See guest list" at the created event.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

In this modification, I used the method of `setGuestsCanSeeGuests` of Class CalendarEvent.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

##### From:

```
eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event);
```

##### To:

```
eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event).setGuestsCanSeeGuests(false);
```

#### Note:

- If you use Calendar API, please use `guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: false`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)

#### Reference:

- [setGuestsCanSeeGuests(guestsCanSeeGuests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setGuestsCanSeeGuests(Boolean))